# Why Nginx ingress only routes requests to pods on the same node in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I built a simple setup of Kubernetes on bare metal. With 1 master and 2 worker nodes:

```
[root@kubemaster helm-chart]$ kubectl get nodes
NAME         STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
kubemaster   Ready    control-plane   53d   v1.26.1
kubenode-1   Ready    <none>          53d   v1.26.1
kubenode-2   Ready    <none>          17d   v1.26.2
```

I installed a simple echo server:

```
[root@kubemaster helm-chart]$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP              NODE         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
echo-67456bbd77-ttgx7   1/1     Running   0          50m   X.X.X.X   kubenode-2   <none>           <none>
```

I've also installed Nginx ingress controller with 2 replicas running on both worker nodes:

```
[root@kubemaster helm-chart]$ kubectl get pods -o wide -n nginx
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP               NODE         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
bkk-ingress-5c56c5868-lhd98   1/1     Running   0          19m   Y.Y.Y.Y   kubenode-1   <none>           <none>
bkk-ingress-5c56c5868-xj8jh   1/1     Running   0          60m   X.X.X.X    kubenode-2   <none>           <none>
```

And I added this ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echo
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: kong.example
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /echo
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: echo
            port:
              number: 80
```

Here is the echo service:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: echo
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: low
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: echo
```

When I test this scenario with calling Nginx controller on KUBENODE_2, where echo app is running as well:

```
curl -i http://KUBENODE_2_IP:MY_PORT/echo -H 'Host: kong.example
```

everything works fine, just as I expected. But if I replace KUBENODE_2_IP with KUBENODE_1_IP, the call results in a timeout. (Ingress controller pod runs on that node as well.) Does anybody know what else shall I configure to make it working?

Both boxes have the MY_PORT opened on them.

Everything is running on CentOS 8 Linux.

If you need any more config to answer this question, please let me know, I can provide everything.

**UPDATE:**

As requested in comments...

```
[root@kubemaster helm-chart]$ kubectl get svc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE              NAME                              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                        AGE
calico-apiserver       calico-api                        ClusterIP   10.102.232.124   <none>        443/TCP                        3d19h
calico-system          calico-kube-controllers-metrics   ClusterIP   None             <none>        9094/TCP                       3d19h
calico-system          calico-typha                      ClusterIP   10.107.28.169    <none>        5473/TCP                       3d19h
default                kubernetes                        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                        3d20h
devops-tools           jenkins-service                   NodePort    10.102.169.34    <none>        8080:32000/TCP                 2d20h
echo                   echo                              ClusterIP   10.103.180.199   <none>        8080/TCP                         3d10h
kube-system            kube-dns                          ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP         3d20h
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper         ClusterIP   10.97.51.241     <none>        8000/TCP                       3d8h
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard              NodePort    10.102.144.46    <none>        443:32321/TCP                  3d8h
nginx                  bkk-nginx-ingress                 NodePort    10.106.141.233   <none>        801:31902/TCP,4431:31903/TCP   2m30s
```

Here is the echo pod:

```
[root@kubemaster helm-chart]$ kubectl get pod echo-6b68cbf67d-xspjh -n echo -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 06aa62993255edd5f3c9c4e6633c21f20d5ead2f2b7836bf69d6c8b12b4b6b26
    cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.29.131/32
    cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 192.168.29.131/32
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-30T09:17:42Z"
  generateName: echo-6b68cbf67d-
  labels:
    app: echo
    pod-template-hash: 6b68cbf67d
  name: echo-6b68cbf67d-xspjh
  namespace: echo
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: echo-6b68cbf67d
    uid: 74c82a2f-40ca-4b84-aa15-13f437c9c1fe
  resourceVersion: "71410"
  uid: f6a859b1-ae4b-4ae6-b7b5-cc19cb752b22
spec:
  containers:
  - image: jmalloc/echo-server
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: echo-server
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      name: http-port
      protocol: TCP
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-api-access-rhx5f
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  nodeName: kubenode-1
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: kube-api-access-rhx5f
    projected:
      defaultMode: 420
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          expirationSeconds: 3607
          path: token
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: ca.crt
            path: ca.crt
          name: kube-root-ca.crt
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
          - fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            path: namespace
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2023-03-30T09:17:42Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2023-03-30T09:17:46Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2023-03-30T09:17:46Z"
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2023-03-30T09:17:42Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: containerd://d6a2d64e322d50a9dc5d4dcec015eb928d6b2a859a73291c2d4e122756503bda
    image: docker.io/jmalloc/echo-server:latest
    imageID: docker.io/jmalloc/echo-server@sha256:57110914108448e6692cd28fc602332357f91951d74ca12217a347b1f7df599c
    lastState: {}
    name: echo-server
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    started: true
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2023-03-30T09:17:46Z"
  hostIP: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  phase: Running
  podIP: 192.168.29.131
  podIPs:
  - ip: 192.168.29.131
  qosClass: BestEffort
  startTime: "2023-03-30T09:17:42Z"
```

**Update for @AagonP**:

```
NGINX Ingress Controller Version=3.0.2 Commit=40e3a2bc24a0b158938c1e1c5e5f8db5feec624e Date=2023-02-14T11:27:05Z DirtyState=false Arch=linux/amd64 Go=go1.19.6
I0405 21:29:29.728053       1 flags.go:294] Starting with flags: ["-nginx-plus=false" "-nginx-reload-timeout=60000" "-enable-app-protect=false" "-enable-app-protect-dos=false" "-nginx-configmaps=nginx/bkk-ingress-config" "-default-server-tls-secret=nginx/bkk-nginx-ingress-default-server-tls" "-ingress-class=nginx" "-health-status=false" "-health-status-uri=/nginx-health" "-nginx-debug=false" "-v=1" "-nginx-status=true" "-nginx-status-port=8080" "-nginx-status-allow-cidrs=127.0.0.1" "-report-ingress-status" "-enable-leader-election=true" "-leader-election-lock-name=bkk-nginx-ingress-leader-election" "-enable-prometheus-metrics=true" "-prometheus-metrics-listen-port=9113" "-prometheus-tls-secret=" "-enable-service-insight=false" "-service-insight-listen-port=9114" "-service-insight-tls-secret=" "-enable-custom-resources=true" "-enable-snippets=false" "-include-year=false" "-disable-ipv6=false" "-enable-tls-passthrough=false" "-enable-preview-policies=false" "-enable-cert-manager=false" "-enable-oidc=false" "-enable-external-dns=false" "-ready-status=true" "-ready-status-port=8081" "-enable-latency-metrics=false"]
I0405 21:29:29.784607       1 main.go:227] Kubernetes version: 1.26.3
I0405 21:29:29.811361       1 main.go:373] Using nginx version: nginx/1.23.3
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: using the "epoll" event method
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: nginx/1.23.3
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: OS: Linux 4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: start worker processes
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: start worker process 14
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: start worker process 15
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: start worker process 16
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: start worker process 17
I0405 21:29:29.876948       1 listener.go:54] Starting Prometheus listener on: :9113/metrics
I0405 21:29:29.877797       1 leaderelection.go:248] attempting to acquire leader lease nginx/bkk-nginx-ingress-leader-election...
W0405 21:29:29.977996       1 controller.go:3877] Using the DEPRECATED annotation 'kubernetes.io/ingress.class'. The 'ingressClassName' field will be ignored.
I0405 21:29:29.979566       1 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Secret", Namespace:"nginx", Name:"bkk-nginx-ingress-default-server-tls", UID:"45245406-83f4-46f7-9504-98e63e954686", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"1224178", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Updated' the special Secret nginx/bkk-nginx-ingress-default-server-tls was updated
I0405 21:29:29.979604       1 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"echoserver", Name:"echoserver", UID:"90866d19-63b4-49a9-9097-663d70c6327a", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"1221186", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'AddedOrUpdated' Configuration for echoserver/echoserver was added or updated 
I0405 21:29:29.979622       1 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"echoserver", Name:"echoserver", UID:"90866d19-63b4-49a9-9097-663d70c6327a", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"1221186", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'AddedOrUpdated' Configuration for echoserver/echoserver was added or updated 
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: signal 1 (SIGHUP) received from 21, reconfiguring
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: reconfiguring
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: using the "epoll" event method
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: start worker processes
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: start worker process 22
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: start worker process 23
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: start worker process 24
2023/04/05 21:29:29 [notice] 13#13: start worker process 25
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 14#14: gracefully shutting down
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 16#16: gracefully shutting down
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 16#16: exiting
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 14#14: exiting
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 14#14: exit
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 16#16: exit
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 15#15: gracefully shutting down
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 15#15: exiting
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 15#15: exit
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 17#17: gracefully shutting down
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 17#17: exiting
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 17#17: exit
I0405 21:29:30.101165       1 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"nginx", Name:"bkk-ingress-config", UID:"2ccfee01-9782-4c26-97c1-36acffda896f", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"1224180", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Updated' Configuration from nginx/bkk-ingress-config was updated 
I0405 21:29:30.101198       1 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"echoserver", Name:"echoserver", UID:"90866d19-63b4-49a9-9097-663d70c6327a", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"1221186", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'AddedOrUpdated' Configuration for echoserver/echoserver was added or updated 
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 13#13: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 14
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 13#13: worker process 14 exited with code 0
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 13#13: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 13#13: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 15
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 13#13: worker process 15 exited with code 0
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 13#13: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 13#13: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 16
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 13#13: worker process 16 exited with code 0
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 13#13: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 13#13: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 17
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 13#13: worker process 17 exited with code 0
2023/04/05 21:29:30 [notice] 13#13: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
I0407 08:39:21.655133       1 leaderelection.go:258] successfully acquired lease nginx/bkk-nginx-ingress-leader-election
```

After this only this segment is repeated numerous times. (I tried it multiple times...)

```
2023/04/08 09:19:05 [error] 22#22: *24 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: XXX.XXX.XXX, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.29.143:80/", host: "XXX.XXX.XXX"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [08/Apr/2023:09:19:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 504 167 "-" "curl/7.87.0" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [08/Apr/2023:10:42:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "curl/7.87.0" "-"
2023/04/13 14:20:57 [error] 22#22: *28 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: XXX.XXX.XXX, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.29.143:80/", host: "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [13/Apr/2023:14:20:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 504 167 "-" "curl/7.87.0" "-"
```

```
[root@kubemaster ~]$ kubectl appkubectl describe ingress echoserver -n echoserver
Name:             echoserver
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        echoserver
Address:
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host                 Path  Backends
  ----                 ----  --------
  apps.besztercekk.hu
                       /   echoserver:80 (192.168.29.143:80)
Annotations:           kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age               From                      Message
  ----    ------          ----              ----                      -------
  Normal  AddedOrUpdated  15s (x4 over 8d)  nginx-ingress-controller  Configuration for echoserver/echoserver was added or updated
  Normal  AddedOrUpdated  15s (x4 over 8d)  nginx-ingress-controller  Configuration for echoserver/echoserver was added or updated
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echoserver
  namespace: echoserver
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: apps.besztercekk.hu
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: echoserver
            port:
              number: 80
```

```
[root@kubemaster ~]$ kubectl describe ingressClass nginx
Name:         nginx
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: bkk
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: nginx
Controller:   nginx.org/ingress-controller
Events:       <none>
```

```
[root@kubemaster ~]$ kubectl describe pod bkk-ingress-8mkf4 -n nginx
Name:             bkk-ingress-8mkf4
Namespace:        nginx
Priority:         0
Service Account:  bkk-ingress-sa
Node:             kubenode-2/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Start Time:       Wed, 05 Apr 2023 23:29:28 +0200
Labels:           app=bkk-ingress
                  controller-revision-hash=5c56c5868
                  pod-template-generation=2
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 99b8a649d5edbbe68d3077ff1a688693495d7eb5ad33a4678b8274eb644ac6a2
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.77.82/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 192.168.77.82/32
                  prometheus.io/port: 9113
                  prometheus.io/scheme: http
                  prometheus.io/scrape: true
Status:           Running
IP:               192.168.77.82
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.77.82
Controlled By:  DaemonSet/bkk-ingress
Containers:
  bkk-nginx-ingress:
    Container ID:  containerd://bab4abc4cc5120c24cbec492397667932d934a73ffa82b08710242a7ef90f0d0
    Image:         nginx/nginx-ingress:3.0.2
    Image ID:      docker.io/nginx/nginx-ingress@sha256:218eec3226b3a130b18090f3f7f244874dd082536e3de53468d0fbd5d357e039
    Ports:         80/TCP, 443/TCP, 9113/TCP, 8081/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -nginx-plus=false
      -nginx-reload-timeout=60000
      -enable-app-protect=false
      -enable-app-protect-dos=false
      -nginx-configmaps=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/bkk-ingress-config
      -default-server-tls-secret=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/bkk-nginx-ingress-default-server-tls
      -ingress-class=nginx
      -health-status=false
      -health-status-uri=/nginx-health
      -nginx-debug=false
      -v=1
      -nginx-status=true
      -nginx-status-port=8080
      -nginx-status-allow-cidrs=127.0.0.1
      -report-ingress-status
      -enable-leader-election=true
      -leader-election-lock-name=bkk-nginx-ingress-leader-election
      -enable-prometheus-metrics=true
      -prometheus-metrics-listen-port=9113
      -prometheus-tls-secret=
      -enable-service-insight=false
      -service-insight-listen-port=9114
      -service-insight-tls-secret=
      -enable-custom-resources=true
      -enable-snippets=false
      -include-year=false
      -disable-ipv6=false
      -enable-tls-passthrough=false
      -enable-preview-policies=false
      -enable-cert-manager=false
      -enable-oidc=false
      -enable-external-dns=false
      -ready-status=true
      -ready-status-port=8081
      -enable-latency-metrics=false
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 05 Apr 2023 23:29:29 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   128Mi
    Readiness:  http-get http://:readiness-port/nginx-ready delay=0s timeout=1s period=1s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      POD_NAMESPACE:  nginx (v1:metadata.namespace)
      POD_NAME:       bkk-ingress-8mkf4 (v1:metadata.name)
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-q2mpq (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-q2mpq:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule op=Exists
Events:                      <none>
```

Comment: Looks like your reaching directly on a node port. Your Service and Ingress are likely ignored. I suspect your Pod is being exposed directly with a NodePort Service but may not be handled by nginx controller. Can you show all services with `kubectl get svc --all-namespaces`?

Comment: Thanks @PierreB for the answer Pierre! The echo service  yaml is up there in the original post. As you can see it is a cluster ip one, so I can’t access it from outside of the cluster. I can even see my requests in the Nginx log on both nodes. The one on the same node where the echo runs is successful, the other reults in a timeout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're showing details for a specific service, my question was to see if other services were also existing :) You can see that with my command above. Also, can you show detailed Pod config with `kubectl get pod -o yaml` ? It's possible another Service or that the Pod directly expose a port on your node

Comment: Aha… Yes I get it now. No, no other services. Only K8S stuff Nginx and the echo service is installed. Nothing else. But I can get it for you. When I’ll be in front of my computer. Writing from phone now…

Comment: Hi @PierreB! I updated the original post with the output of the requested queries. As you see, I played a little bit with the K8S Dashboard and Jenkin install. Those things hasn't changed the behaviour. However if you want I can remove them...

Comment: If I call the Nginx on the 31902 port, it only forwards the request to echo pod if I call the nginx pod on the same node as the echo lives. Does not really matter on which node it is. I tried it with both. I replaced the echo pod to node 1, and called the nginx on node2, it was the same behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Your Kubernetes config seems fine, normally a `NodePort` service is accessible through all  nodes of your cluster, so you should be able to use both nodes without issue. Maybe one of your node has iptables or another network-related config (but not Kubernetes related) preventing it from working. Check out this issue, it might provide some idea: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/100434

I'm sorry but I cannot help further

Comment: Hi Pierre B! Thanks for the answer. You might be able to give me some more hints... Can you tell me what sort of IPTABLE rules shall I look for what can prevent this from working properly? You might have an example rule what breaks this scenario?

Comment: You can check if on your host you are able to reach the problematic port externally. CentOS seems to be using `firewalld`, you can checkout if there's a diff between your node on this config, or start a small server on the node directly listening on the port and try to reach externally see if it works (you can then see if the problem comes from host config or Kubernetes)

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried this. They are totally the same. And I can reach the node from outside of Kubernetes. It is some problem with Kubernetes, I think. So, I am starting to give it up. The simplest scenario is not working on bare metal. And paying some well known K8S provider is expensive, if I want the same cpu and memory conditions what I have on the bare metal. So, I think K8S is not the solution. It is just simply not working for me. Maybe some other container orchestration system or just simple docker compose, I don't know, I'll have a look around what's available.

Comment: I also turned off firewall on host nodes. I thought, and all the other forums says it is some problem with the host network. But after completely turning off the firewalls, it's the same. One node can't access pods on another one. So, it's a Kubernetes issue.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting all nodes? I had similar effects due to a change of overlay network implementation.

Comment: @bkk were you able to resolve this issue? I'm facing the exact same problem

Comment: Hi @Tejash JL! No, not really. I am not sure what is happening. I gave up on Kubernetes as per the simplest task is a challenge for it, and I am looking at other similar solutions. I tried everything what was suggested here in every comments. But if you have some ideas I am still opened for that as per I still have my environment set up, and would be easier to apply chages on that rather then installing completelly new solution.

Comment: @bkk Im not sure what is the actual issue with calico. I tried multiple steps nothing worked. Later, I moved on to flannel and everything works fine. I have added my steps to clean up and setup the flannel.

Answer (score 0):

On the KUBENODE_1_IP node you don't have any active "Echo" application.

Try changing the replication of "Echo" to 2, make sure the second pod goes to the KUBENODE_1_IP node and you will see that it will work for you.

Either way, you're bypassing the Service; if you point to the Service, then replacing the IP of the Node with the full DNS name of the Service, you would always reach your application.
Example:
`SERVICE-NAME.NAMESPACE-NAME.svc.cluster.local`

Here are some useful links:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

https://medium.com/the-programmer/working-with-clusterip-service-type-in-kubernetes-45f2c01a89c8

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/cluster-ip-allocation/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What do you mean by pointing to the service? I am using an ingress controller and that should route the traffic to the service.  I point to the ingress which is sending the request to the service. Or am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: I understood that you ask why you reach the application "Echo" pointing to the node where this application runs and not when you point to the other node.
This is because intra clusters are not pointing to ClusterIP, but directly to nodes. 
For the Ingress speech, that seems correct.

Comment: Yeah, I try to access the service using an ingress. The echo app is  a ClusterIP, it is only available from the cluster. But I have ingress controller which is targeting the echo service. And it works if I  call the ingress controllel instance living on the same node as the echo server lives.

Comment: Ok so, picking up
your example, CURL kong.example/echo only works if you run it logged into node kubenode-2 and not from node kubenode-1?

Comment: If so, it would be inexplicable, precisely because the kong.example host points to the Echo service which in turn points to the "backend" Pods.

Comment: Yeah, that’s the case. If I go to ingress controller at kubenode_1, it can’t access the service and can’t get to the echo server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252772/discussion-between-glv-and-bkk).

Comment: @glv That doesn't matter wherever your pod is placed to NodePort be working, right! It should work from specified port from any of the node available in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to install [`kube-proxy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-proxy/), the Kubernetes network proxy running on each node?

Without it, your Nginx ingress controller running on KUBENODE_1 will have no way to redirect your request to the echo pod.

Refer to [Install the kube-proxy addon with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/generated/kubeadm_init_phase_addon_kube-proxy/)

Comment: Hi YwH! Thanks for your answer. I have kube-proxy pods running on both nodes and on the master as well. It comes by default with the installation and is is in the kube-system namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while using Calico CNI. I replaced Calico with [Flannel](https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel#deploying-flannel-manually) and it works fine.

The steps I followed are as below:

- Cluster clean up [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#tear-down)
- Remove files from `/etc/cni/net.d` directory in all nodes
- Initialize a new cluster with `sudo swapoff -a && sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=<public ip>`
- Deploy [flannel](https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel#deploying-flannel-with-kubectl)
- Join all the nodes to cluster

Comment: Thanks @Tejash JL! I'm going to try this. Will let you know how it works by accepting your solution. But it won't be today, this week is pretty busy for me.

Comment: Hi @Tejas JL! I managed to try out your suggestion. It is the same or even worse. Generally ingress only works when I "curl" to the same node where the target service lives. I tried with both worker nodes, and if I address the one where I have the echo service, it works fine. But when I target the other node, timeout comes. And why it is worse than before? Because, I lost connection to external services. E.g. my Jenkins pod can't resolve any hostnames, but it just worked fine with Calico. So, unfortunately Flannel did not help me out. I am opened for other suggestions as well.